# SQL combining GROUP BY and SUM

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need help with SQL. I have an sqlite table like so;

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (datetime DATE, type TEXT, amount REAL)
```

I need a query which would sum up amount for each type AND year-month (as you can see the year is also extracted since the data can span several years). I've come to something half-way, but I'm a bit rusty on SQL.

```
sqlite> SELECT strftime('%Y',datetime) AS year, strftime('%m',datetime) AS month, type, amount FROM mytable ;

2009|06|Type1|-1000.0
2009|06|Type1|-100.0
2009|06|Type2|-100.0
2009|07|Type1|-214.91
2009|07|Type2|-485.0
```

I've tried a number of combinations of SUM and GROUP BY on my query above but none of them does what I want. What I want is a result something like:

```
2009|06|Type1|-1100.0
2009|06|Type2|-100.0
2009|07|Type1|-214.91
2009|07|Type2|-485.0
```

Yes, type should be a foreign key, I simplified things to make it easier to ask the question :)

Comment: sum up for each Year-Month or just for Month?

Comment: Sorry, year-month, clarified now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
SELECT strftime('%Y',datetime) AS year, 
       strftime('%m',datetime) AS month, 
       type, 
       Sum(amount) As Amount 
FROM mytable 
Group By 1, 2, 3
```

### Note

Some DBs don't support group by index so you would have to do this.

```
SELECT strftime('%Y',datetime) AS year, 
       strftime('%m',datetime) AS month, 
       type, 
       Sum(amount) As Amount 
FROM mytable 
Group By strftime('%Y',datetime), 
       strftime('%m',datetime), 
       type
```

Comment: Careful when using ordinals for GROUP BY (and ORDER BY) - if the column order changes, there will be impact.

Comment: Yes, laziness can come back to bite you.