# Totalling scores in mysql

Tags: mysql

Im looking for a way to group and add up scores in mysql

Table would be something like this:

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Gary | 50 |
| Rob | 62 |
| Bill | 42 |
| Rob | 34 |
| Gary | 24 |
| Gary | 35 |

To Produce :

| Name | Total Score |
| --- | --- |
| Bill | 42 |
| Rob | 96 |
| Gary | 109 |

Total Score being in descending order

Comment: It's very simple case. Look below link for example: https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql57/52f078b0b5d4f6ce204433b988dcd66d/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL combining GROUP BY and SUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639906/sql-combining-group-by-and-sum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below:

```
  SELECT sum(Score) as total,Name FROM youtable GROUP BY Name ORDER BY total
```